# Verify text on web page and then get the location in selenium webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Is their any way we can find the location of Text present on web page after verifying its presence using selenium webdriver in java

Code used to verify the text present of not:

```
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

driver.getPageSource().contains("Mercury Tours!");
if(true)
{
    System.out.println("Test Case Pass");
} 
else    
    System.out.println("Test Case Fail");
```

`Mercury Tours!` is text on a web page. Now how to find location after getting the `text = true`.

I tried using `getLocation()`, but failed.

Please let me know the solution on this asap.

Comment: First of all your code will always end up in `if`, because you are not checking the result of verification. At the minimum the working code should be:   `<...> if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Mercury Tours!"))`. Secondly what do you mean by "location": coodinates (which is what `getLocation()` returns), location in the dom (e.g. xpath), or location within text page (e.g. something returned by Java's `indexOf`)?

Comment: Are you searching for the `div`/`span`/etc. that contains that text? Is that what "find the location" means? If not, what do you mean? Also, as noted above, you need to assign the `.contains()` to a bool so you can properly check your if. Please be more specific when asking questions so we know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the complexity of DOM structure and lack of unique attributes on the elements, I think you should just use xpath to find an element with text. Unfortunately this is the only option I see as of now unless others have better suggestions. Ask front end developers to provide unique attributes so that you can find elements easily instead of relying on text of the element.

```
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//font[contains(text(),'Mercury Tours')]"));
if(element.isDisplayed()) {
   System.out.println("Test Case Pass");
} else    
    System.out.println("Test Case Fail");   
}
```